# network access lost when I connect to VPN

Tags: networking, dns, vpn

When I connect to a VPN using forticlient I lose access to all other sites (outside of the VPN).  I thought the problem was with my DNS and `resolved` but now I realise that I cannot even `ping 8.8.8.8` so it must be something even more fundamental, right?

When I'm connected to the VPN here's what `ifconfig -a` tells me (loopback edited out):

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::279f:54fe:977f:4e6c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 18:03:73:e6:32:f2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 74896  bytes 58598268 (55.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 59257  bytes 11405705 (10.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xe1500000-e1520000 

vpn: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1400
        inet 10.50.192.11  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.50.192.11
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 500  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 59  bytes 13713 (13.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2155  bytes 172229 (168.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And after I disconnect from the VPN, when I can use my default DNS, etc `ifconfig` tells me

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.5  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::279f:54fe:977f:4e6c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 18:03:73:e6:32:f2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 75682  bytes 58794111 (56.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 59981  bytes 11559277 (11.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xe1500000-e1520000
```

Edit (to improve readability): `ip route` gives

```
$ ip route
default via 10.50.192.14 dev vpn scope link default via 192.168.1.254 dev eno1 proto dhcp metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.5 metric 100
193.1.103.33 via 192.168.1.254 dev eno1
```

and

`resolvectl` gives

```
Global Protocols:
+LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported resolv.conf mode: foreign Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8 DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 DNS Domain: google.com Link 2

(eno1) Current Scopes: 
DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6 Protocols:
+DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 Link 9 

(vpn) Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 Protocols:
+DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported DNS Servers: 10.220.1.10 10.220.1.11
```

FWIW I'm running Debian with

```
$ uname -a
Linux foirfe 5.15.0-2-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.15.5-1 (2021-11-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

All suggestions gratefully appreciated.

Edit 2:
`traceroute 8.8.8.8`:

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  193.1.101.1 (193.1.101.1)  12.708 ms  12.723 ms  12.736 ms
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
    :
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

For comparison when I am not connected to the VPN here's what traceroute says:

```
$ traceroute 8.8.8.8
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.1.254)  0.565 ms  0.763 ms  0.974 ms
 2  95-45-22-1-dynamic.agg2.chd.lmk-mlw.eircom.net (95.45.22.1)  5.355 ms  5.445 ms  6.072 ms
 3  eth-trunk113.hcore1.mlw.core.eircom.net (86.43.255.90)  12.017 ms  12.097 ms  12.177 ms
 4  eth-trunk15.hcore1.prp.core.eircom.net (86.43.254.143)  17.245 ms  17.396 ms  17.496 ms
 5  lag-20-br2-6cr-hcore1-prp.br2.6cr.border.eircom.net (86.43.12.215)  12.620 ms  12.889 ms  12.961 ms
 6  72.14.211.86 (72.14.211.86)  14.130 ms  11.139 ms  11.057 ms
 7  * * *
 8  dns.google (8.8.8.8)  10.721 ms  9.487 ms  9.671 ms
```

and, when connected, `httping` gave

```
$ httping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8:80 (/):
^CGot signal 2
--- http://8.8.8.8/ ping statistics ---
1 connects, 0 ok, 0.00% failed, time 22643ms
```

while `nslookup` gave

```
$ nslookup 8.8.8.8
nslookup: parse of /etc/resolv.conf failed
```

The `/etc/resolv.conf` file is a symlink:

```
 ls -lu /etc/resolv.conf /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root  27 Jan  3 15:47 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 373 Jan  3 12:44 /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

and this looks like:

```
$ cat /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "resolvectl status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver dnsserverip
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
search google.com
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: Is this a corporate VPN?  If so it's likely the software is being instructed to force all traffic via the VPN.  This is common in corporate settings to prevent a workstation bypassing corporate controls (such as firewalls).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  It's a university VPN though my trouble is when I'm at home.  The IT people there are at a loss and say the trouble is on my end.

Comment: I'd start by investigating where the traffic is routed and whether DNS lookup works. `ip route`, `nslookup <some_external_url`, `traceroute <some_external_url`. Chances are your university routes your traffic via a proxy, which means `ping` won't work. An alternative that might be useful is `httping`.

Comment: Please also include the output of `ip route` and the name servers in /etc/resolv.conf (and maybe `resolvectl` if you are using systemd-resolved)

Comment: `ip route`:$ ip route
default via 10.50.192.14 dev vpn scope link 
default via 192.168.1.254 dev eno1 proto dhcp metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.5 metric 100 
193.1.103.33 via 192.168.1.254 dev eno1

Comment: resolvectl 
Global
         Protocols: +LLMNR +mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: foreign
Current DNS Server: 8.8.8.8
       DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        DNS Domain: google.com

Link 2 (eno1)
Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4 LLMNR/IPv6
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

Link 9 (vpn)
Current Scopes: DNS LLMNR/IPv4
     Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
   DNS Servers: 10.220.1.10 10.220.1.11

Comment: Apologies for poor formatting of outputs of `ip route` and `resolvctl`

Comment: It's better to [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/684812/edit) the post with that info so that you can apply proper formatting

Comment: Did `traceroute`, `nslookup` and `httping` give any useful info? Is your university using a proxy?

Comment: The httping command did not yield anything useful, just silence, really.  I will post the output of the three commands as part of my original question next.  While the nslookup command complained about parsing /etc/resolv.conf this happens regardless of the VPN connection.  I'll post that, too.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know if my uni is using a proxy.  Thanks.

Comment: `nameserver dnsserverip` does not look right, and in combination with `search google.com` it makes me suspect you've been modifying the dns settings, so revert those changes first. Next, try `httping google.com` and `nslookup google.com` instead. The former won't get any response from google's dns server (8.8.8.8) and as for the latter, you want to try resolving a hostname to an ip address, not the other way around.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132858/discussion-between-healyp-and-frippe).